# Why can cookies not be set in axios interceptors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am building a nuxt app that is populated by an external rails api. I use a jwt as a session identifier for the rails api. Simply put, whether my calls the the api are executed server or client side, when the server response carries an authorization header, i want to add it to the store AND add it to a cookie so it can be used for subsequent calls to the server.

I decided to try and solve this problem by defining a plugin which ads response intercepters to my axios config. There, when a response includes a token in its header i simply add it to the cookie and store. I am using the npm package 'cookie-universal-nuxt' which supposedly exposes a consistent api for getting/setting cookies across the server and client.

The problem is when i call `$cookie.set('jwt', token')` i get the error `cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'`

What does this mean? I am using the standard nuxt server setup (not express). Any help is much appreciated.

```js
//plugins/axios.js
export default (ctx) => {                                                                                                                                                                
  let {                                                                                                                                                                                  
    app: { $cookies, $axios },                                                                                                                                                           
    res,                                                                                                                                                                                 
    req,                                                                                                                                                                                 
    store,                                                                                                                                                                               
    redirect,                                                                                                                                                                            
  } = ctx;                                                                                                                                                                               
  $axios.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');                                                                                                                                  
  $axios.setHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');                                                                                                                                

  const insideGenerate = process.static && process.server;                                                                                                                               
  // $axios.defaults                                                                                                                                                                     
  $axios.interceptors.response.use(                                                                                                                                                      
    function(response) {                                                                                                                                                                 
      console.log(`[$axios Plugin] Response on ${process.client ? 'client' : 'server'}`);                                                                                                
      if (response.headers.authorization) {                                                                                                                                              
        const token = response.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ');                                                                                                                   
        $cookies.set('chiApi', token);                                                                                                                                                 
        if (!insideGenerate) store.commit('UPDATE_AUTH_COOKIE', token[1]);                                                                                                               
      }                                                                                                                                                                                  
      return response;                                                                                                                                                                   
    },                                                                                                                                                                                   
    function(error) {                                                                                                                                                                    
      console.log(`[$axios Plugin] Error on ${process.client ? 'client' : 'server'}`, JSON.stringify(error));                                                                            
      if (error.response.headers.authorization) {                                                                                                                                        
        const token = error.response.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ');                                                                                                             
        $cookies.set('chiApi', token);                                                                                                                                                 
        if (!insideGenerate) store.commit('UPDATE_AUTH_COOKIE', token[1]);                                                                                                               
      }                                                                                                                                                                                  
      return Promise.reject(error);                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                    
  );                                                                                                                                                                                     
};
```

```js
//nuxt.config.js
export default {                                                                                                                                                                         
  server: {                                                                                                                                                                              
    port: 4041,                                                                                                                                                                          
  },                                                                                                                                                                                     
  mode: 'universal',                                                                                                                                                                     
  /*                                                                                                                                                                                     
   ** Headers of the page                                                                                                                                                                
   */                                                                                                                                                                                    
  router: {                                                                                                                                                                              
    middleware: ['pc-check'],                                                                                                                                                            
  },                                                                                                                                                                                     
  head: {                                                                                                                                                                                
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',                                                                                                                                           
    script: [{ src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js' }],                                                                                              
    meta: [                                                                                                                                                                              
      { charset: 'utf-8' },                                                                                                                                                              
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },                                                                                                              
      {                                                                                                                                                                                  
        hid: 'description',                                                                                                                                                              
        name: 'description',                                                                                                                                                             
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || '',                                                                                                                              
      },                                                                                                                                                                                 
    ],                                                                                                                                                                                   
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],                                                                                                                 
  },                                                                                                                                                                                     
  /*                                                                                                                                                                                     
   ** Customize the progress-bar color                                                                                                                                                   
   */                                                                                                                                                                                    
  loading: { color: '#fff' },                                                                                                                                                            
  /*                                                                                                                                                                                     
   ** Global CSS                                                                                                                                                                         
   */                                                                                                                                                                                    
  css: ['~assets/scss/main.scss'],                                                                                                                                                       
  /*                                                                                                                                                                                     
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App                                                                                                                                            
   */                                                                                                                                                                                    
  plugins: [                                                                                                                                                                             
    '@/plugins/axios',                                                                                                                                                                   
    '@/plugins/equalHeights.js',                                                                                                                                                         
    '@/plugins/chiApi.js',                                                                                                                                                               
    '@/plugins/vuelidate.js',                                                                                                                                                            
    '@/plugins/global.js',                                                                                                                                                               
  ],                                                                                                                                                                                     
  /*                                                                                                                                                                                     
   ** Nuxt.js modules                                                                                                                                                                    
   */                                                                                                                                                                                    
  modules: [                                                                                                                                                                             
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage                                                                                                                                               
    '@nuxtjs/axios',                                                                                                                                                                     
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',                                                                                                                                                             
    'cookie-universal-nuxt',                                                                                                                                                             
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',                                                                                                                                                                     
  ],                                                                                                                                                                                     

  proxy: [],                                                                                                                                                                             
  /*                                                                                                                                                                                     
   ** Axios module configuration                                                                                                                                                         
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options                                                                                                                                               
   */                                                                                                                                                                                    
  axios: {                                                                                                                                                                               
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options                                                                                                                        
    host: 'yadayada',                                                                                                                                                                
    port: 4040,                                                                                                                                                                          
    prefix: '/api',                                                                                                                                                                      
  },                                                                                                                                                                                     
  /*                                                                                                                                                                                     
   ** Build configuration                                                                                                                                                                
   */                                                                                                                                                                                    
  build: {                                                                                                                                                                               
    /*                                                                                                                                                                                   
     ** You can extend webpack config here                                                                                                                                               
     */                                                                                                                                                                                  
    //sourceMap: true,                                                                                                                                                                   
    extractCSS: true, // external css when pages are generated                                                                                                                           
    extend(config, ctx) {                                                                                                                                                                
      config.module.rules.push({                                                                                                                                                         
        test: /\.(html)$/,                                                                                                                                                               
        exclude: /node_modules/,                                                                                                                                                         
        loader: 'html-loader',                                                                                                                                                           
      });                                                                                                                                                                                
    },                                                                                                                                                                                   
  },                                                                                                                                                                                     
};
```

I expect a rendered vue page to arrive client side with the jwt token passed along as a cookie.

Comment: I use the exact same package and exact same configuration and do not have this issue, if it's of any help.

Comment: You forgot to add credentials:true option inside your axios object in the nuxt config js file